# python split a text file function

Tags: python, regex, list, function, split

I wrote a tokenize function that basically reads a string representation and splits it into list of words.

My code:

```
def tokenize(document):
    x = document.lower() 
    return re.findall(r'\w+', x)
```

My output:

```
tokenize("Hi there. What's going on? first-class")
['hi', 'there', 'what', 's', 'going', 'on', 'first', 'class']
```

Desired Output:

```
['hi', 'there', "what's", 'going', 'on', 'first-class']
```

Basically I want the apostrophed words and hypen words to remain as a single word in list along with double quotes. How can i change my function to get the desired output.

Comment: Can you split on spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w+` matches one or more *word characters*; this does not include apostrophes or hyphens.

You need to use a [character set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) here to tell Python exactly what you want to match:

```
>>> import re
>>> def tokenize(document):
...     return re.findall("[A-Za-z'-]+", document)
...
>>> tokenize("Hi there. What's going on? first-class")
['hi', 'there', "what's", 'going', 'on', 'first-class']
>>>
```

You'll notice too that I removed the `x = document.lower()` line.  This is no longer necessary since we can match uppercase characters by simply adding `A-Z` to the character set.